# How to move a variable from global to local inside of a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

My simple test program adds and subtracts numbers correctly.  However I'd like to turn my global variable, `counter` into a local variable.  I can't logically see how to do this and still keep the program running.  Is there a way to position `counter` so that it is only accessible from the `addNumber` or `subtractNumber` closures?  Thanks so much!

```js
'use strict';
 
var counter;
counter = 0;
 
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].addEventListener('click', addNumber);
document.getElementsByClassName('box')[1].addEventListener('click', subtractNumber);
document.getElementsByClassName('box_answer')[0].textContent = 'The answer is ' +counter;

function calculateNumber(x) {
  counter += x;
  displayNumber();
}
 
function displayNumber() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('box_answer')[0].textContent = 'The answer is ' +counter;
}
 
function addNumber() {
  calculateNumber(1);  
}
 
function subtractNumber() {
  calculateNumber(-1); 
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
 
.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box_answer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">addNumber</div>
<div class="box">subtractNumber</div>
<div class="box_answer"></div>
```

Comment: Do you want `addNumber` and `substractNumber` to remain global? Or do you want to hide them too?

Comment: `addNumber` and `subtractNumber` can remain global because they are being called by `addEventListener`.  Thanks!

Comment: If they're called just by the event listeners then you can hide those event listeners too (in an IIFE that is). Or are they called from somewhere else (so they must be global)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do it is to take all of your code and get it out of the global scope, which you should always strive to do anyway. This is generally done by wrapping all of your code in an Immediately Invoked Function Expression.

Also, you don't need a separate function for adding and subtracting. Just have each click event handler call a single function and pass the value to use to that function.

Lastly, unless you have a specific use case, avoid DOM API calls like:

- .getElementsByName()
- .getElementsByTagName()
- .getElementsByClassName()

because they all return "live" node lists, which cause the entire DOM to be re-scanned for matching elements every time the node list is referenced in your code. This can lead to dramatic performance hits. Instead, use the more modern:

- .querySelector()
- .querySelectorAll()

and, of course:

- .getElementById()

These three API's will handle most of your DOM query needs.

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
 
  // .getElementsByClassName returns a "live" node list, which is not recommended
  // for most use cases because it requires re-scanning the DOM every time the node
  // list is used. querySelector() and .querySelectorAll() are the modern  successors 
  // to that.
  var answer = document.querySelector('.box_answer'); 
  
  // Find box by its unique class (or id) so that you don't scan the entire DOM only to
  // throw away all found elements but the one you want:
  document.querySelector('.box.add').addEventListener('click', function() { doMath(1); });
  document.querySelector('.box.subtract').addEventListener('click', function() { doMath(-1); });

  var counter = 0;

  function doMath(x) {
    counter += x;
    displayNumber();
  }
 
  function displayNumber() {
    answer.textContent = 'The answer is ' + counter;
  }
 
})();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
 
.box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
  cursor:pointer;  /* Change pointer to let user know they can click */
  
  /* Prevent text in element from being selected. Helps when lots of clicking happens. */
  user-select:none;   
}

.box_answer {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="box add">addNumber</div>
 <!-- Give each box a different class (or id) to differentiate one from the other. -->
<div class="box subtract">subtractNumber</div>
<div class="box_answer">The answer is:</div>
```

Comment: I'm going to start using `.querySelectorAll()`.  I knew that `.getElementsByClassName()` was dynamic but I never thought about how that would increase workload.  Great tip!

Answer (score 2):

You could move all of the variables and functions inide of an [IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

```js
'use strict';
 
void function () {
    function calculateNumber(x) {
        counter += x;
        displayNumber();
    }
 
    function displayNumber() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('box_answer')[0].textContent = 'The answer is ' +counter;
    }
 
    function addNumber() {
        calculateNumber(1);  
    }
 
    function subtractNumber() {
        calculateNumber(-1); 
    }

    var counter = 0;

    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0].addEventListener('click', addNumber);
    document.getElementsByClassName('box')[1].addEventListener('click', subtractNumber);
    document.getElementsByClassName('box_answer')[0].textContent = 'The answer is ' + counter;
}();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 2rem; font-family: sans-serif; }
.box { margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px; color: white; background-color: blue; }
.box_answer { padding: 10px; background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<div class="box">addNumber</div>
<div class="box">subtractNumber</div>
<div class="box_answer"></div>
```